# Linker cannot find libpq library while cross-compiling rust application

Tags: postgresql, rust, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile rust application using cross. Hello application compiles with no issue. The problem is when I try to use a diesel package with `postgres` support which depends on `libpq` library.

I did the installation of the `libpq-dev` package on my machine and I included a `sys-pq` package to my Cargo.toml, but it did not help.

How can I solve this?

Error:

```
➜ cross build --target armv7-unknown-linux-musleabi
   Compiling libc v0.2.138
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
...
  = note: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabi/9.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-musleabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
➜ cat Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "webserver"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
env_logger = "0.9"
futures-util = { version = "0.3.17", default-features = false, features = ["std"] }
json = "0.12"
log = "0.4"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenvy = "0.15"
# Cross dependencies
pq-sys = "0.4.7"

[profile.release]
strip = true
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
```

Comment: Did you install `libpq-dev` _for your target_ on your development machine? Note that it is very likely that you won't find it in your package manager and will need to install it from source.

Comment: @Jmb thanks for reply, Yea that is the case, however there are still so less support for cross-compiling rust apps. :/