# "Cannot find -libpq" when using cross for cross-compiling

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, libpq

I'm currently trying to cross-compile a rust application (with diesel and postgres) to Ubuntu from Windows. I ran `cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, and everything goes smoothly until the very last step when it gives a nasty error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
|
= note: LC_ALL="C" P...
... ,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using docker, and I've tried putting libpq.dll basically everywhere. I also installed libpq-dev and libpq5 on my WSL, yet none of that has worked.

I'm not entirely sure what would be affecting this, as I can't find basically anything about this issue. I cut out the giant wall of text note, since it didn't show anything useful. I know that it can't find the libpq.dll/libpq.so, but I don't know where to put those and how to get libpq.so.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useless to put a Windows  dll file anywhere because Linux cannot use it.

Comment: If you are cross-compiling on Windows for Linux, WSL has nothing to do with it. If you are compiling in WSL, you are not cross-compiling, it is a normal Linux compilation. Why not just do that?

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing afaik since Cross just runs it in a docker. The problem is that it can't seem to link the libpq file

Comment: Docker uses WSL but it is isolated from the host OS. It doesn't know what is installed there. It probably uses its own instance, not sure. For your purposes it is its own independent OS installation. You need to put libpq.so and everything needed by libpq.so in whatever place the linker on the docker can see it (normally /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74735540/5397009

Comment: I need to know how to get libpq.so then, I have literally looked everywhere and I can't find it

Comment: I thought that installing libpq5 or libpq-dev would have it automatically find it but I guess it didn't